# Inserting data into SQL database that needs to be linked

Tags: python, sql

I'm not sure what exactly the wording for the problem is so if I haven't been able to find any resource telling me how to do this, that's most likely why.

The basic problem is that I have a webcrawler, coded in Python, that has a 'Recipe' object that stores certain data about a specific recipe such as 'Name', 'Instructions', 'Ingredients', etc. with 'Instructions' and 'Ingredients' being a string array.

Now, the problem I have comes when I want to store this data in a database for access from other sources.

A basic example of the database looks as follows:

(Recipes)
r_id, name, ....

(Ingredients)
i_id, name, ....

(RecipeIngredients)
r_id, i_id.

Now, specifically my problem is, how do I make sure I'm not duplicating ingredients and how do I insert the data so that the ingredient is linked to the id of the current Recipe object?

I know my explanation is bad but I'm struggling to put it into words. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hello, can you review and give feedback for these answers? We don't know what method can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question (how do I make sure I'm not duplicating ingredients?), if I understand well, is basically put your primary key as (i_id, name) in the table ingredients. This way you guarantee that is impossible insert an ingredient with the same key (i_id, name).

Now for the second question (how do I insert the data so that the ingredient is linked to the id of the current Recipe object?). I really don't understand this question very well. What I think you want is link the recipes with ingredients. This can be made with the table RecipeIngredients. When you want to do that, you simple insert a new row in that table with the id of the recipe and the id of the ingredient. If isn't this what you want sorry, but I really don't understand.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I found it hard to explain.

For your first point, my i_id is auto increment at the moment so that means there would never be a duplicate with both the same i_id and name. Would this still work?

For the second point, I understand the RecipeIngredients part and have that table but how do I get the r_id of the Recipe I want to link it to when inserting? Do I just use a Select before it and pull it out?

Comment: Ok then put as your PK the `i_id` and add the constrain UNIQUE to the column `name`. This way you can't have two ingredients with the same name. 

Yeah! You should do a SELECT by name (because is UNIQUE should only return 1 row). Then insert it `i_id` with the `r_id` of the recipe that you want associated in the table RecipeIngredients

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I think you are lack of data processing and database design experience. But don't worry, it can learn by doing.

For the second question, let's get to the point.
Recipes are relational with ingredients in database, But actually every recipe's ingredients is different, ingredients include many food element -- eggs , meat, flour , and etc.
When you create the RecipeIngredients table, you can't show that one of recipes use the ingredients. RecipeIngredients's i_id should store multiple ingredients
, not one ingredient. It need to fix.

I recommend the RecipeIngredients table set r_id(OneToOneField) and i_ids(TextFeild) columns. The comment is model field, if you are programming in django.

I assume your models is like this:

```
# Recipes model
class Recipes(models.Model):
    r_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

# Ingredients model
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    i_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()

# RecipeIngredients model
class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    r_id = models.OneToOneField(Ingredients, primary_key=True)
    i_ids = models.TextField()
```

Next process data:

```
# fake data
the_recipe =  "Pasta Sauce with Meatballs"
the_ingredients = ["Pasta Sauce", "meatballs", "spaghetti"]

# save the recipe in database
recipe_object = Recipes(name="the_recipe").save()

# save the ingredients in database
i_ids_arrary = []
for i in the_ingredients:
    ingredient_object = Ingredients(name=i).save()
    i_ids_arrary.append(str(ingredient_object.i_id))
i_ids_string = ",".join(i_ids_arrary)

# save RecipeIngredients
RecipeIngredients(r_id=recipe_object, i_ids=i_ids_string).save()
```

I think it can complete most of the tasks in detail. I hope that you can refer to it.